# Find the Point(s) where the tangent(s) to the graph of $y=(x^2 - 25)^3$ are parallel to the x-axis.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that the derivative and the slope of the tangent line equal 0. Therefore, I took the derivative of $y$ and after that, I put the derivative equal to $0$. I solved for it and I got $x=5$, $x=-5$, and $x=0$. Am I doing this right so far? If so, where do I go from here? If not, then what should I do then?

[image]

Comment: That looks right.

Comment: But what would be the points? (-5,0), (5,0), and (0,0)?

Comment: I assume that by **points**, they mean points on the graph, not just the values of $x$. So $x=\pm 5$ gives you points $(\pm 5, 0)$ and $x=0$ gives you $(0,-25^3)=(0,-15625)$. Otherwise, it's correct.

Comment: When $x=0$, we get $(0,(-25)^3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is right indeed to have horizontal tangent we need

$$y'=6x(x^2-25)=0 \implies x=0 \quad \lor \quad x=\pm 5$$

Comment: So would the points be (5,0), (-5,0) and (0,-15625)?

Comment: @P1081Yes of course! That's also right.